# Is "gambling in relationship" idiomatic?

Tags: idiomatic-language

I am wondering if the expression "gambling in relationship" is idiomatic. By that, I mean "go into a relationship that has very little chance of lasting a long time."

Here's an example:

> Dating a girl who hates people who are timid like me is gambling in
>   relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the idiomatic phrase is *to take a gamble*. Example: *He's taking a gamble dating that woman, he's not her type.*

Comment: Or *gambling **with the** relationship*, if you want a normal sounding sentence that isn't an actual idiom.

Comment: @JasonBassford normal sounding? You can use that but it seems it would be lot more awkward in sentence structure.